# Create Soap Message without SOAP-ENV

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I am trying to create following soap message programatically using `javax.xml.soap.*`  classes.

How can I produce this xml exactly? 
when I create the xml message root tage begins with `<SOAP-ENV:Envelope` instead of  `<env:Envelope`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='ISO-8859-9'?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Header>
        <mm7:TransactionID
            xmlns:mm7="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-5-MM7-1-2"
            env:mustUnderstand="1">
            TXN_ID-2011521232323
        </mm7:TransactionID>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <mm7:SubmitReq xmlns:mm7="urn:mm7SubmitReq">
            <MM7Version>5.6.0</MM7Version>
            <Content allowAdaptations="true" />
            <MessageClass>1</MessageClass>      
        </mm7:SubmitReq>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: The `SOAP-env` is just a namespace which is defined in the XML document itself.  Typically, you would use a framework to generate this XML, such as Apache CXF.  Do you have a WSDL handy for this SOAP service?

Answer (score 0):

as Tim suggested the prefix name should not matter.

the prefix `SOAP-ENV` comes from [com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.name.NameImpl#SOAP_ENVELOPE_PREFIX](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/com/sun/xml/internal/messaging/saaj/soap/name/NameImpl.java#43)

you can modify this using reflection. but It is not recommended to do so.